# It's showing unreachable statement error

Tags: android, unreachable-statement

I'm trying to make a toast on item selected but it's showing unreachable statement error.

My code is:

```
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  btn.performLongClick();
                }
            }
    );
    registerForContextMenu(btn);
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("For Optimum Results");
    menu.add(0,v.getId(),0,"Hi");
    menu.add(0,v.getId(),0,"Hello");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    if(item.getTitle()=="Hi"){
        Toast.makeText(this,"hi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what this "unreachable code" stuff means?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Also you compare after return statement, which is the main problem, please learn some java's basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two type of error:

1)return super (`return super.onContextItemSelected(item)`) , it means that you return your method at first line so lines below not execute.

2)wrong comparing String (`item.getTitle()=="Hi"`)

correct code should be like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   //return super.onContextItemSelected(item);//remove this line
   if(item.getTitle().equal("Hi")){// also maybe you want to check not null for item.getTitle()
       Toast.makeText(this,"hi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   return true; 
}
```

Comment: @user8027365 your welcome , so please mark it as true answer. tnx